# Cant connect Node.js to MariaDB

Tags: node.js, mariadb

Ok so I tried to connect node.js with my server mariaDB with this code

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
     host: 'mydb.com', 
     user:'myUser', 
     password: 'myPassword',
     connectionLimit: 5
});
async function asyncFunction() {
  let conn;
  try {
    conn = await pool.getConnection();
    const rows = await conn.query("SELECT 1 as val");
    console.log(rows); //[ {val: 1}, meta: ... ]
    const res = await conn.query("INSERT INTO myTable value (?, ?)", [1, "mariadb"]);
    console.log(res); // { affectedRows: 1, insertId: 1, warningStatus: 0 }

  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  } finally {
    if (conn) return conn.end();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately.It's doesn't work.The strange thing is I didnt recieve any eror messages.I wanna know In which I did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you invoke asyncFunction()? Like (async () => { await asyncFunction() })();

Comment: could you send me an example? Because I don't quite understand what are you talking about?I'm a beginner.So.Sorry If I dont quite get it.

Comment: @Phat What is your OS and node version & mariadb version?

Answer (score 0):

There! Here is what I use

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100,
    host            : 'localhost',
    user            : 'rashid',
    password        : config.get('turing-password'),
    database        : config.get('turing-db-name'),
    multipleStatements:true
})

module.exports.connect = pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) 
        logger.info('we could not connect to the database');
    
    logger.info('We successfully connected to the database');
  })
```

Please make sure if your running on localhost use the host as localhost

Comment: I've tested the script.Unfortunately.In my case.It doesn't work.

Comment: Please try to share the error that receive with me so that I can help